# Add a shadow to the bottom of a header when scrolled

Tags: jquery, html, css

The goal is to add a shadow to the bottom of a (fixed positioned) header when the window is scrolled.  But for some reason, this code does not seem to be working. When I scroll, nothing happens. Any help will be appreciated.

**CODE**

The java script is written in the head part of my html document.

```js
<script>
$(window).scroll(function() {     
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
    if (scroll > 0) {
 $("#header-home").addClass("shadow");
    }
    else {
 $("#header-home").removeClass("active");
    }
});
</script>
```

```css
#header-home{
    position:fixed;
    width:100%;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    background-color:#fff;
    z-index:900;
}

.active { 
    box-shadow: 0 4px 2px -2px #f1f1f1; 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
<header id="header-home">
    <!-- header content here -->
</header>
```

Comment: you add class `shadow` but in your css it's name is `active`

Comment: voting for close for typo mistake

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You had a couple of problems. First, you were applying class "shadow" but removing class 'active' (should have been shadow/shadow), and secondly your box-shadow code didn't work. Use [this link](http://www.cssmatic.com/box-shadow) to construct box-shadow code.

This example demonstrates that your code was basically correct once the aforementioned errors were corrected.

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {     
  var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
  if (scroll > 100) {
    $("#header-home").addClass("shadow");
  }
  else {
    $("#header-home").removeClass("shadow");
  }
});
```

```css
html,body{height:2000px;}
#header-home{position:fixed; height:50px;width:100%; top:0; left:0; xbackground-color:black; xcolor:#fff; z-index:900;}

.active { box-shadow: 0 4px 2px -2px #f1f1f1; }
.shadow {border:3px solid orange;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
  
<header id="header-home">
        header content here
</header>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code you have

```
$("#header-home").addClass("shadow");
```

Which I expect should be

```
$("#header-home").addClass("active");
```

Comment: as was already said in the comments. no need to make an answer out of a comment, especially of someone else's comment.

Comment: @vsync I was writing my answer as he made my comment, and didn't notice that until after. Additionaly, you're to avoid answering questions in comments, as per the title: "Use comments to ask for more information or suggest improvements. Avoid answering questions in comments."